# ¿Cómo eliminar u ocultar contenido de etiqueta <a> HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo un menú responsive con links como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que al disminuir el screen de la pantalla la palabra "Mi Cuenta" desaparezca y solo quede la etiqueta span con el icono.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar u ocultar el contenido de la etiqueta  `<a>`  pero sin borrarla por completo para que conserve la etiqueta `<span>`?

O, ¿de que otra forma sería posible que queden solo los iconos?

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieses el código como texto y no como imagen, así es más fácil leerlo (y hay muchos usuarios que usan teléfonos/tabletas y no se ve bien).

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta es mi primera pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con mediaQuerys, indicas el tamaño en el cual deseas que el texto no este visible.

Encierra el texto del `a` en otro `span` con clase `a-text`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    a span.a-text {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que tienes con CSS sería hacer que en pantallas pequeñas el tamaño del texto del `a` sea 0, mientras que el `span` dentro del `a` tenga un valor positivo. Al tener tamaño 0, será "invisible" (a la vista, porque los lectores de pantalla lo seguirán detectando y lo leerán).

Un ejemplo (verás sólo un icono, pero si le das a "Página completa" se verá el icono y también el texto del enlace):

```css
.icon-icono::before {
  content: "♥";
}

@media all and (max-width:767px) {
  nav ul li a {
    /* el texto del enlace será invisible */
    font-size: 0;
  }
  nav ul li a span {
    /* pero el icono seguirá teniendo tamaño normal */
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-icono"></span> Enlace</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

La idea sería que pusieras un valor que creas conveniente en el @media query (he puesto 767px como prueba para que se pueda ver la diferencia entre el marco de la respuesta y si le das al botón de "Página completa").